# Find the distance of the closest pair of points ( c )

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef struct
{
    int x,y;
}point;

double distance(point p1[], point p2[], int i)
{
    double d = sqrt((pow(p2[i+1].x-p1[i].x,2)) + (pow(p2[i+1].y-p1[i].y,2)));
    return d;
}

int main()
{
    int size,i;
    double d;
    printf("Enter number of point: ");
    scanf("%d",&size);
    point p[size];
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter point %d: ",i+1);
        scanf("%d,%d",&p[i].x,&p[i].y);
    }
    d = distance(p[0].x,p[0].y,0);
    for(i=0;i<size-1;i++)
    {
        if( d > distance(p[i+1].x,p[i+1].y,i))
           {
               d = distance(p[i+1].x,p[i+1].y,i);
           }
    }
    printf("Closest pair distance = %.4lf",d);
}
```

I have been trying to finish this homework for a while and I'm not sure on how to fix this.

The output supposed to look like this:
[image]

This is what I got:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to [edit] your questions to improve them, like telling us the expected behavior versus the actual behavior, and what debugging you have made and what it told you. And text should be copy-pasted *as text*.

Comment: So what is your problem? Do you get any errors?

Comment: the output I got is nothing. but the thing it return is random numbers that's not 0. Let me edit in the picture

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings and fix all of them.  You are accidentally treating an int as a pointer, causing your program to access invalid memory.

Comment: Your teacher should really be teaching you how to read the warnings too.

Comment: Hint: How do you call the `distance` function? With what arguments? What arguments does the `distance` function really expect?

Comment: This is what I'm currently understanding. I need to change the line that I called distance function to `distance(i+1,i+1,i+1)` ? because I want to input i+1 , i+1 , i+1 into the bracket of p1 , p2  and i

Comment: I recommend you change the `distance` function to this: `double distance(point p1, point p2);`. Then calculate the distance between `p1` and `p2`. No pointers, no indexes, just two points.

Comment: I'm not sure on how to compare between 2 points if I do it without pointers. Can you hint me about it ?

Answer (score 2):

I have done some changes. Read the comments marked with `// CHANGE HERE` to understand the changes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    // CHANGE HERE: double instead of int
    double x, y;
} point;

// CHANGE HERE: just accept two points whose distance needs to be calculated
double distance(point p1, point p2)
{
    return sqrt((pow(p1.x -  p2.x, 2)) + (pow(p1.y - p2.y, 2)));
}

int main()
{
    int size, i, j;
    double d;
    
    printf("Enter number of points: ");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    
    // CHANGE HERE: use malloc for variable sized arrays
    point* p = malloc(size * sizeof(point)); 
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        // CHANGE HERE: read double instead of int
        printf("Enter point %d: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%lf,%lf", &p[i].x, &p[i].y);
    }
    
    // CHANGE HERE: store a high value by default
    d = DBL_MAX;
    for (i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
    {
        // CHANGE HERE: to get the exact pair of points with closest distance
        // you need to compare the distance of each point with the rest
        for (j = i + 1; j < size; j++)
        {
            // CHANGE HERE: pass previous and current point to distance
            double dist = distance(p[i], p[j]);
            if (d > dist)
            {
               d = dist;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("Closest pair distance = %.4lf", d);
    
    // CHANGE HERE: don't forget to free malloc()ed memory
    free(p);
    return 0;
}
```

As mentioned by @tstanisl, you can also use [hypot](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/hypot) function present in `math.h`, like:

```
double distance(point p1, point p2)
{
    return hypot(p1.x - p2.x, p1.y - p2.y);
}
```

Comment: May I ask why you make x , y double ?

Comment: Look at the image when number of points is equal to 5. Some points are floating point values.

Comment: consider using `hypot` to compute the distance between points. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/hypot

Comment: @tstanisl, thanks for that, will include that my answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

First, I think your `distance` function should get two points, and not two points arrays. you also don't need to pass the index. this way your function will only do what it should do: calculate the Euclidean distance.

```
double distance(point p1, point p2)
{
    double d = sqrt(pow(p2.x-p1.x,2) + pow(p2.y-p1.y,2));
    return d;
}
```

Second, in your `main` function, do you want to check only the distance between consecutive points or between any point? I think you want the second option but decide for yourself:

first option:

```
for(i=0;i<size-1;i++)
{
    if( d > distance(p[i],p[i+1]))
    {
        d = distance(p[i],p[i+1]);
    }
}
```

second option:

```
for(i=0;i<size-1;i++)
{
    for (j=i+1;j<size;j++)
    {
        if( d > distance(p[i],p[j]))
        {
            d = distance(p[i],p[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

notice I set `j=i+1` because first, i don't want to calculate `distance(p[i],p[i])` because that will always be 0 and that is the minimal value `distance` can return. secondly it's sufficient to test only for `j>i` values because `distance(p[i],p[j])==distance(p[j],p[i])`

I hope that cover everything

Comment: when `i=size-1` you get `j=size` so it is not necessary

Comment: You mean `i = size - 2` and `j = size - 1`, but yeah, [fair enough](https://godbolt.org/z/hWTnjxanq).